# A question about compact support

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

Support is defined as the closure of $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$. Now consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\chi_{(0,1)}$. So the support is $[0,1]$ which is compact. However, any continuous function with compact support is uniformly continuous. $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ but it is not uniformly continuous.

I am confused. Could anyone explain where I made a mistake.

Comment: A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous, Why are you claiming that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: If one of the submissions answered your question, don't forget to upvote, and click the checkmark to accept the best answer, @S_Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not continuous. As surprising as it may seem.

What is the value of $f(0)$?

$f(0)$ is well defined. $f(0) =0$ as $0$ is outside of $(0,1)$.

But what is $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) $ ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\chi_{(0,1)}$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ nor on $[0,1]$. It has jump discontinuities at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

It is continuous on $(0,1)$ of course, but its support is all of $(0,1)$ which is not compact. Because, as a subspace of $(0,1)$, the closure of $(0,1)$ is still $(0,1).$ So it does not have compact support on this domain.

But if you further restrict to any compact set within $(0,1)$, you will see that the function is actually uniformly continuous. Eg it is uniformly continuous on the interval $[1/4,3/4]$.